# I Want to use folium package to show the trackings in chronological order of different ids given a certain datetime with its latitude and longitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap, folium

```
data[data["fixedAt"] <= date_]

    idTracking  fixedAt             latitud      longitud
3   12953       2021-02-23 15:54:24 -34.665799  -58.472854
4   12953       2021-02-23 18:14:46 -34.665792  -58.472878
5   12967       2021-02-23 18:02:02 -34.604630  -58.530462
6   12953       2021-02-24 08:06:34 -34.665807  -58.472890
7   12953       2021-02-24 09:18:15 -34.665762  -58.472910
... ... ... ... ...
208 12953       2021-02-24 14:00:14  -34.665781 -58.472893
209 12953       2021-02-24 14:44:56  -34.665760 -58.473002
210 12969       2021-02-24 14:35:52  -34.729679 -58.470623
211 12953       2021-02-24 15:24:56  -34.665822 -58.472893
212 12967       2021-02-24 15:23:15  -34.604569 -58.530470

from folium.features import DivIcon

map_osm = folium.Map(location=[-34.665792, -58.472878], zoom_start=4)

for _, row in data.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[row["latitud"], row["longitud"]], 
                                radius=3).add_to(map_osm)
    
    folium.Marker(location=[row["latitud"], row["longitud"]], icon=DivIcon(icon_size=(150,36), icon_anchor=(0,0),
        html='<div style="font-size: 8pt">{}</div>'.format(row['idTracking']))).add_to(map_osm)

map_osm
```

[Example of what the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkkha.png)

I also want to color it given its idTracking and example would be a directional graph where i can see the history in the map of each shipment.

I was trying to use folium but I can only get the different points for each latitude and longitude.

Thanks! to anyone that can help me

Answer (score 0):

I like using folium's AntPath() for this type of thing

Starting with some data

```
idTracking             fixedAt    latitud   longitud
0        12953 2021-02-23 15:54:24 -34.665799 -58.472854
1        12953 2021-02-23 18:14:46 -34.665792 -58.472878
2        12953 2021-02-24 08:06:34 -34.765807 -58.472890
3        12953 2021-02-24 09:18:15 -34.665762 -58.492910
4        12953 2021-02-24 14:00:14 -34.665781 -58.472893
5        12953 2021-02-24 14:44:56 -34.665760 -58.493002
6        12953 2021-02-24 15:24:56 -34.565822 -58.472893
7        12967 2021-02-23 18:02:02 -34.604630 -58.530462
8        12967 2021-02-24 15:23:15 -34.604569 -58.530470
9        12967 2021-02-25 16:23:15 -34.704569 -58.540470
10       12967 2021-02-26 17:23:15 -34.804569 -58.630470
```

I use Pandas' groupby to work with a "route" at a time then simply pass a route in the form of list of points to AntPath()

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import AntPath
import pandas as pd

cd = {12953 : 'blue', 12967: 'red'}

map_osm = folium.Map(location=[-34.665792, -58.472878], zoom_start=10)

for idt, grp in df.sort_values(['idTracking', 'fixedAt']).groupby('idTracking'):
    route = grp[['latitud', 'longitud']].values.tolist()
    AntPath(route, tooltip=idt, color=cd[idt]).add_to(map_osm)
map_osm
```

[image]

Comment: Also, here's an NB that put together before I knew about AntPath() that plots polylines with rotated triangles to convey direction.  You might find it interesting https://github.com/bobhaffner/medium_posts/blob/master/folium_lines/folium_arrow_lines.ipynb